# Laravel 5.5, using 3 dropdown button filter without resetting first and 2nd filter

Tags: javascript, php, css, laravel

I have 3 Dropdown menu to filter applicants data in my list, from the database
but when I filter with the 2nd filter, the 1st filter will reset it..
I want to do the filter records the 1st filter and then move to 2nd filter without resetting it. and then apply filters to get the data

this is my first time using laravel and everything inside it.
If anyone has a way how this is work, I'm really thank you for that
I'm really appreciate that.

this is the screenshot of the button
[the applicants list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52jJu.png)

this is the controller

```
public function index()
{
    $branches = \App\Branch::all();
    $batches = \App\Batch::all();
    $users = \App\User::all();
    $user_details = \App\UserDetail::all();

    $applicant_info = DB::table('applicants')
    ->join('user_details', 'applicants.fk_user_details_id', '=', 'user_details.user_detail_id')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'user_details.fk_users_id')
    ->join('batches', 'applicants.fk_batches_id', '=', 'batches.batches_id')
    ->join('branches', 'applicants.fk_branches_id', '=', 'branches.branches_id')
    ->select('applicants.*', 'user_details.*', 'branches.*', 'batches.*', 'users.*')
    ->orderBy('applicants_id', 'asc');

    if(request()->has('country')){
        $applicant_info = $applicant_info->where('applicants.applicant_country', request('country'));
    }

    if(request()->has('branch')){
        $applicant_info = $applicant_info->where('branches.branch_name', request('branch'));
    }

    if(request()->has('batch')){
        $applicant_info = $applicant_info->where('batches.batch_name', request('batch'));
    }


    $applicant_info = $applicant_info->get();

    // $applicants = $applicants->paginate(5)->appends(['country' => request('country')]);

    $branch = \App\Branch::orderBy('branch_name')->pluck('branch_name')->unique();

    $batch = \App\Batch::orderBy('batch_name')->pluck('batch_name')->unique();

    $countries = \App\Applicant::orderBy('applicant_country')->pluck('applicant_country')->unique();


    return view('backend.applicant_management.applicant_list', ['applicant_info'=>$applicant_info, 'branches'=>$branches, 'batches'=>$batches, 'users'=>$users, 'countries'=>$countries, 'branch'=>$branch, 'batch'=>$batch]);

}
```

and this is the view.blade

```
<div class="pull-right">
   <div class="btn-group">
      <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" aria-expanded="false">Branch Name<span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu" name="branch">
         <li><a href="/applicant_list">All Branch</a>
            @foreach($branch as $branch)
         <li><a id="filterbranch" href="/applicant_list/?branch={{ $branch }}"> {{ $branch }}</a></li>
         @endforeach
      </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="btn-group">
      <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" aria-expanded="false">Batch Number<span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu" name="batch">
         <li><a href="/applicant_list">All Batch</a>
            @foreach($batch as $batch)
         <li><a href="/applicant_list/?batch={{ $batch }}"> {{ $batch }}</a></li>
         @endforeach
      </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="btn-group">
      <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" aria-expanded="false">Country<span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu" name="country">
         <li><a href="/applicant_list">All Country</a></li>
         @foreach($countries as $country)
         <li><a href="/applicant_list/?country={{ $country }}"> {{ $country }}</a></li>
         @endforeach
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you are redirecting, you should send back the select value so that it can be retained back in the dropdown

Comment: you can use ajax to filter every dropdownlist data.

Comment: If someone filters the list by 'applicant_country', Let say By 'Malaysia' and filter the batch with SG-Bugis
then what result you want to show?

Comment: @DsRaj just the applicant with name "Xavier"

Comment: add one form in the view and submit the form with the selected result

Comment: ah it's okay now, i add 1 more custom route in the view.blade to get, save and use the url that button triggered for the next filter @DsRaj